# Using an IFrame with a webBrowser in c# Windows Forms Application that, when the webBrowser size is changed, it also changes the IFrame's size

Tags: c#, html, css, iframe

So I need a c# Windows Forms Application that shows a responsive page in an IFrame, which is inside a webBrowser, on a button click. The problem is when i change the size of the application, it also changes the webBrowser applicattion since its anchored, the webSite doesn't change its item's sizes/locations.

I have oppened the webSite by itself and i have confirmed it changes when you resize it, which as led me to believe that the IFrame doesn't realise that the webBrowser has been resized.

[Button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG5w6.png)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI9qL.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzUTt.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.